# How long the homologous arms of the "repair" sequence must be to do homologous recombination?

Tags: recombination

I am trying to figure out the details of the homolougous recombination in order to be able to insert a certain piece of DNA in the host genome after double strand break.. Does anybody know how long the homology arms of the repair template must be ? Can the left arm be longer than the right one? I have read several papers which have different sizes 90 bp vs kb..
In my case, i am not so much preoccupied by off target but the insertion should occur also on the desired site possibly at high frequency and as fast as possible.
Thank you,
Paola

Answer (score 2):

As little as 14bp of homology can work. See this [reference](http://mcb.asm.org/content/4/11/2253).

I would recommend at least a length of 90bp but 1kb is probably overkilled. Yes both arms can have different length (staying in the same order of magnitude).